# How to execute stored procedure in oracle that contains two insert statements?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I'm trying to execute a stored procedure that contains two insert statements, however I'm unsure how to do this or is there a better way to do so. The stored procedure has two insert statements which insert data into two different tables.

I have tried `execute new_order()` see below then passing in the values but get this error `ERROR at line 1: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'NEW_ORDER' ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored` really appreciate the help.

```
 execute new_order(
'4', 
'O223PS562', 
'Test Test', 
'test@test.co.uk', 
'123 Test Street', 
'Newcastle Upon Tyne', 
'Tyne and Wear', 
'NE98 4TN', 
'123456789', 
'7.97', 
'11-apr-2021',
'5', 
'4', 
'2', 
'2', 
'3073748221',
'2', 
'Brand new',
'1.99', 
'2.00');
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE new_order
-- define the variables for orders and order_item tables
(
    -- variables for the orders table
    p_order_id IN INT, 
    p_order_num IN CHAR,
    p_name IN CHAR, 
    p_email IN CHAR,
    p_address IN VARCHAR2,
    p_city IN VARCHAR2,
    p_province IN VARCHAR2,
    p_postcode IN VARCHAR2,
    p_telephone IN NUMBER,
    p_total IN NUMBER,
    p_order_date IN DATE,
    -- variables for the order_item table
    p_order_item_id IN INT,
    p_product_id IN INT,
    p_seller_id IN INT,
    p_sub_order_number IN CHAR,
    p_quantity IN INT,
    p_condition IN CHAR,
    p_unit_price IN NUMBER, 
    p_cost_charge IN NUMBER
)
AS
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Insert attempted');

    -- Insert data into the order table
    INSERT INTO orders(
        order_id, 
        order_number, 
        billing_name, 
        billing_email, 
        billing_address, 
        billing_city, 
        billing_province, 
        billing_postcode, 
        billing_telephone,
        billing_total,
        order_date)
    values(
        p_order_id, 
        p_order_num,
        p_name,
        p_email,
        p_address,
        p_city,
        p_province,
        p_postcode,
        p_telephone,
        p_total,
        p_order_date
        );

    -- Insert data into the order_item table
    INSERT INTO order_item(
        order_item_id,
        order_id,
        product_id,
        seller_id,
        sub_order_number,
        quantity,
        condition,
        unit_price,
        cost_charge
        )
    values(
        p_order_item_id,
        p_order_id,
        p_product_id,
        p_seller_id,
        p_sub_order_number,
        p_quantity,
        p_condition,
        p_unit_price,
        p_cost_charge
        );

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Insert succeeded');

    EXCEPTION
     WHEN others THEN   
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Insert rejected');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('SQL Error Code:  ' || SQLCODE);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('SQL Error Message:  ' || SQLERRM); 
        ROLLBACK;
END;
/
```

Comment: The error indicates that the code that is being used to call this procedure, which you haven't included, is passing in either the wrong number of parameters or the wrong data types.  Since you didn't include the code used to call the procedure, there isn't much that anyone can offer beyond the error message.

Comment: When I remove one of the insert queries it executes fine since it's passing in the right amount of parameters, but I want the procedure to execute both queries. Can't you execute a procedure with two insert queries or is there a way to merge them?

Comment: You can have as many SQL statements as you'd like in a procedure.  When you remove one of the insert statements, are you removing some of the parameters to the procedure since those parameters aren't being used?  When you add the second insert statement, are you changing the method that calls this procedure to pass in the new parameters?

Comment: Yes I removed the variables for the order_item however the `p_order_id` parameter is used for both queries. I don't think so I just added another insert query below the first one. Would you be able to show me an example @JustinCave?

Comment: Show an example of what?  If you post the code you're using to call the procedure when it generates the error, we can probably tell you what is wrong with the caller.

Comment: @JustinCave I have added the command I was using to execute the procedure above alongwith the error. I'm passing in the right amount parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, you're passing the wrong number or type of parameters.

I would strongly recommend using named parameter syntax if you're trying to call a procedure with this many parameters.  Otherwise, humans tend to have difficulty noticing when they omit a parameter or pass parameters in the wrong order if they're trying to figure out what they're passing for the 20th parameter to a procedure.  Personally, I'd tend to refactor a procedure long before I was trying to pass in 20 parameters.  Something as simple as passing in one or two record types might make the code much easier to read and understand.

I've changed your call to use named parameters and added comments for where you've made mistakes.

```
execute new_order(
  p_order_id => 4, -- Pass in a number rather than using implicit conversion
  p_order_num => 'O223PS562', 
  p_name => 'Test Test', 
  p_email => 'test@test.co.uk', 
  p_address => '123 Test Street', 
  p_city => 'Newcastle Upon Tyne', 
  p_province => 'Tyne and Wear', 
  p_postcode => 'NE98 4TN', 
  p_telephone => '123456789', 
  p_total => 7.97, -- Pass in a number rather than using implicit conversion
  p_order_date => to_date('11-apr-2021', 'DD-mon-YYYY'), -- Pass in a date rather than using implicit conversion
  p_order_item_id => 5, -- Pass in a number rather than using implicit conversion
  p_product_id => 4, -- Pass in a number rather than using implicit conversion
  p_seller_id => 2, -- Pass in a number rather than using implicit conversion 
  p_sub_order_number => 2, -- Pass in a number rather than using implicit conversion 
  p_quantity => 3073748221, -- Do you really want the quantity to be in the billions?  That seems unlikely.  
                            -- Perhaps there was supposed to be a phone number parameter
  p_condition => '2', -- That doesn't look like a condition.  Probably meant to be a unit price
  p_unit_price => 'Brand new', -- Here we have a definite error.  p_unit_price is a number but you can't connvert
                               -- the string 'Brand new' to a number.  I assume that was really supposed to be the
                               -- condition
  p_cost_charge => 1.99, -- Pass in a number rather than using implicit conversion
  '2.00' -- And here we have a value being passed in but no equivalent parameter
);
```

Comment: The procedure executed sucessfully but for some reason the data for the first insert query did not populate in the table.

Comment: @Jal - That's probably a separate question.  Post a reproducible test case.  Ideally, set one up on dbfiddle.uk that you link to that shows us the problem.  My guess is that there was an exception, your exception handler is swallowing the exception unless the caller happens to have enabled `dbms_output`, and the information about what the error was is getting lost.  I'd much rather have no exception handler than the exception handler in your question.

Comment: Ok thank you I'll try and debug it from here.