# ORA-00904: invalid identifier error when trying to execute PL/SQL stored procedure using nested tables

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm trying to execute a stored procedure which uses a nested table, however I get the following error. I've checked the values that are being passed into the collection and it's passing in the right amount of values. I did an insert query and it worked fine so I'm unsure why the procedure isn't executing.

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
28/5     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
30/5     PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "ORDER_ITEMS": invalid identifier
SQL>
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE order_item AS object(
    order_item_id INT,
    order_id INT, 
    product_id INT,
    seller_id INT, 
    sub_order_number CHAR(10),
    quantity INT, 
    condition CHAR(100),
    unit_price NUMBER, 
    cost_charge NUMBER
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE order_items AS Table of order_item;
/

CREATE TABLE Orders (
 order_id INT CONSTRAINT PKEY_order PRIMARY KEY,
 order_number CHAR(10),
 billing_name CHAR(100),
 billing_email CHAR(100),
 billing_address VARCHAR2(100),
 billing_city VARCHAR2(100),
 billing_province VARCHAR2(100),
 billing_postcode VARCHAR2(100),
 billing_telephone NUMBER(25),
 billing_total NUMBER,
 order_date DATE,
 Items order_items)
 Nested Table Items Store As Orders_Item
/
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_new_order
(
    p_order_id IN INT, 
    p_order_num IN CHAR,
    p_name IN CHAR,
    p_email IN CHAR,
    p_address IN VARCHAR2, 
    p_city IN VARCHAR2,
    p_province IN VARCHAR2,
    p_postcode IN VARCHAR2,
    p_telephone IN NUMBER, 
    p_total IN NUMBER,
    p_order_date IN DATE,
    -- Order items
    p_order_item_id IN INT, 
    p_product_id IN INT, 
    p_seller_id IN INT,
    p_sub_order_number IN CHAR, 
    p_quantity IN INT,
    p_condition IN CHAR, 
    p_unit_price IN NUMBER, 
    p_cost_charge IN NUMBER
)
AS
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Insert attempted');

    INSERT INTO Orders (order_id, order_number, billing_name, billing_email, billing_address, billing_city, billing_province, billing_postcode, billing_telephone, billing_total, order_date, order_items)
    VALUES (p_order_id, p_order_num, p_name, p_email, p_address, p_city, p_province, p_postcode, p_telephone, p_total, p_order_date, order_items(
        order_item(p_order_item_id, p_order_id, p_product_id, p_seller_id, p_sub_order_number, p_quantity, p_condition, p_unit_price, p_cost_charge)));

    COMMIT;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Insert succeeded');

    EXCEPTION
     WHEN others THEN   
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Insert rejected');
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('SQL Error Code:  ' || SQLCODE);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('SQL Error Message:  ' || SQLERRM); 
      ROLLBACK;
END;
/
```

Ideally I want to have the insert query to do this in the stored procedure, which works when I execute this query.

```
INSERT INTO Orders VALUES (1, 'P396XT47','Test', 'test@test.co.uk', 
    'test', 'test', 'test' ,'DL99 9UU', '123456789', '57.78', '19-apr-2021', order_items(
    order_item(1, 1, 1, 1, '3026143053', '1', 'Brand new', '53.49', '0'),
    order_item(2, 1, 2, 2, '3029608429', '1', 'Brand new', '1.99', '2.00')));
```

Comment: What is `order_items_collection`?  If you actually run the code you posted, the actual error you'll get is that `order_items_collection` is an invalid identifier.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1f1a0a6141fa3d608b6b252ebc417f38

Comment: Sorry that was a typo it was meant to be `order_item` I have changed that in the insert query in the procedure but still receiving the same error

Comment: Then the next typo is that the column in the table is named `items`.  The column list in your `insert` statement incorrectly says `order_items`. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=188a682c6ad184444cb59afc9c2f693c

Comment: Thanks @JustinCave I see now that has compiled successfully. Could you give me an example on how to execute this stored procedure as I'm running into errors such as `wrong number or types of arguments`

Comment: How are you calling it?  I assume based on the error that you're not passing in the correct number or type of arguments.  I'm hoping this is a homework assignment that requires you to use nested tables.  In the real world, you'd really want separate `order` and `order_item` tables and you'd want separate procedures for creating an order and inserting the order items.  You asked a question some time ago related to problems with this same error calling this same procedure https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67044667/how-to-execute-stored-procedure-in-oracle-that-contains-two-insert-statements

Comment: I'm calling it like this `exec insert_new_order(1, 'P396XT47','Test', 'test@test.co.uk', 'test', 'test', 'test' ,'DL99 9UU', '123456789', '57.78', '19-apr-2021', order_items(
    order_item(1, 1, 1, 1, '3026143053', '1', 'Brand new', '53.49', '0'),
    order_item(2, 1, 2, 2, '3029608429', '1', 'Brand new', '1.99', '2.00')));` yes it is trying to understand concept about nested tables

Comment: You can't pass a collection to the procedure.  It is defined to take scalars so you could only ever insert a single `order_item`.  You could change the procedure declaration to take an `order_items` collection rather than all the scalar values.  Of course, you'd need to change the implementation as well since the parameter definitions changed.

Comment: Ok so the procedure won't be able to handle multiple order items, I think this is where it gets tricky because you wouldn't want the order to be produced more than once but only the order items

Comment: Which is why you'd normally want separate procedures.  As I said, though, you could also change the implementation to take in an `order_items` collection rather than the 9 scalar values it currently takes.

Comment: I think I'll just use two separate procedure like you've mentioned seems the best way to do this. Otherwise it's going to get really messy passing alot of values.

Comment: As a side observation, not related to your question ... you have 'billing_telephone NUMBER(25)'.   Telephone "numbers" are not really _numbers_.  The are character strings that, by _modern_ convention use only numeric _characters_.  (What? You think the only reason there are letters on your telephone keypad is to enable text messages?)   If you try to make them NUMBER, then you run the risk of losing any leading zeros.  If you have a data element for which it is totally illogical to apply any math operation, then it is not really a NUMBER.